# Why is there an "Error 424" in my vba Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do an easy little search and replace function in excel 2019 and I'm just new to vba so please help ... 
I don't know why there is an error in this Code and it doesn't highlight anything

I  don't know what to try

```vb
Sub One_Find()
    Dim FieldRange As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Set FieldRange = Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address
    Do
        Set FieldRange = Cells.FindNext(FieldRange)
    Loop While FieldRange.Address <> FirstAddress
    Set FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"

End Sub
```

It just says 'Error 424' or Object needed but I dont know where

Comment: remove the `Set` from the last line.  you do not "Set" a value.

Comment: Note that `FiedRange` will be `Nothing` if `.Find` doesn't find anything - a member call against `Nothing` (e.g. `FieldRange.Address`) will mercilessly throw error 91.

Comment: @tartaruga_casco_mole same error, different cause, and zero explanation for the actual cause in that dupe candidate. This question was very likely asked and answered before, yes, but that is a bad dupe target.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks a lot I now don't have the Error 424 any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *object is required*, because you're using the `Set` keyword here:

> ```
> Set FieldRange.Value = "WORKS" ' string
> ```

And here:

> ```
> Set FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address ' string
> ```

There are 2 types of assignments in VBA: `Let`, and `Set`. When you assign *values*, you are making `Let` assignments:

```
[Let] foo = 2 + 2 ' foo is an integer value
[Let] bar = "something" ' bar is a string value
```

Note that the `Let` keyword is obsolete/redundant, and is usually omitted.

When you assign *object references*, you are making `Set` assignments:

```
Set foo = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") ' foo is a Range object reference
Set bar = Application ' bar is an Application object reference
```

You can let-coerce an object that has a *default member* into a value:

```
[Let] foo = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'implicit: Range.Value
[Let] bar = Application 'implicit: Application.Name
```

But you can't "set-coerce" a value into an object reference:

```
Set foo = "something" 'illegal; an object is required on the right-hand side
```

Don't use the `Set` keyword when you are assigning *values*.

Comment: Omg, never heard about `Let` this way. I learned always like `MyVariable = MyValue`. Actually first time I saw `Let` was when I was trying to learn class modules because the custom properties. Awesome answer.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns `Property Let` is *exactly* this though: `[Let] foo.Something = 42` invokes the `Property Let` accessor of the `Something` property; `Set foo.Something = New Something` invokes the `Set` accessor of that `Something` property ;-)

Comment: I haven't seen `Let` used since I wrote Basic on the ZX-81 in the early 80's (where it was mandatory). I'd completely forgotten about it, but your answer makes perfect sense when explained this way. Bravo.